# How to transfer value from char variable to char array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I have `char data` variable which gives (o/p comes from pc's hyper terminal and i am comparing its inside microcontroller) me known string with known length like `"ASDF"`.

Now I want to store this variable's o/p to a `char` array `char dataarray[5];`

And I had other char array `char newdata[8]="ASDF\r\n";` so that I can compare both string using `if(strcmp(dataarray[i],name2) == 0)`

something like

```
char data;
char dataarray[5];    
char newdata[8]="ASDF\r\n";
if(strcmp(dataarray[i],newdata[j]) == 0)
```

So what should I need to change?

---

```
void main()
{
   char *data;    
   char *old;    
   char *match;    
   char *nomatch;       
   nomatch = "not";    
   match = "yes";    
   old = "HJB";     
   int m;

   USARTInit(25);    //UBRR = 51

   //Loop forever

   while(1)
   {            
        data=USARTReadChar();

        if(strcmp(data,old) == 0)
        {
          for(m=0;m<3;m++)
          {
            USARTWriteChar(match[m]);
          }
        }
        else{USARTWriteChar(nomatch);
    }              
}
```

Comment: Did you try `strcpy`?

Comment: your question itself is confusing..which variable is suppossed to be used where?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.

Comment: No i hadnt used strcpy

Comment: @SouravGhosh : Question is so simple...that my i/p is in char variable form n i need to compare it with char array

Comment: @hardik.. so is the answer. :-)

Comment: @haccks : as per i know that strcpy can copy two strings in to desired...but  thats not my desired task. Anyway how can u solve above matter using strcpy?

Comment: I think Mr. @haccks got confused (so did I, for the first time) by your question statement. `strcpy()` is not of much use here.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: i dont understood that how can i compare char variable with char array??

Comment: Once you have formed the _string_, you can surely use `strcmp()` as you wanted.

Comment: I am little bit confused, what does `USARTReadChar` return? A `char *` ? Does it have a static buffer and returns the pointer to it? Or does it read and return one char then the `char* data` is wrong.

Comment: Yes there is inside a microcontroller, there is inbuilt buffer which can store data..n we can receive character one by one at a time

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of array indexing to achieve this. Please check the below pseudo-code

```
 char data = 0;
 char dataarray[5] = {0};       //initialize
 for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)   //you can customize, but leave space for null
 {
   data = somefunc();    //somefunc() returns a char value
   //something else, if you want. maybe some sanity on data itself
   dataarray[i] = data;         
 }
 dataarray[i] = 0;               //null terminate the array
```

Then, you can use `dataarray` for any string related operation, say `strcmp()`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change size of `dataarray`which is having size **Five**, means excluding `null character` you can store only **Four** values in it. `newdata` is already having **Six** values in it, so when you will do

`if(strcmp(dataarray[i],newdata[j]) == 0)`

then it will always fail. You need to change that **size of dataarray** as well so that sometime that condition will get `true` and it will work properly.

**EDIT**

As per edited question I made this code for understanding. Code Explanation is given in comments

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 100    
void main()
{
   char data[MAX_LENGTH] = {'\0'}; 
   char old[] = "HJB";    
   char match[] = "yes";    
   char nomatch[] = "not";       
   int m;
   int count = 0;
   USARTInit(25);    //UBRR = 51

   //Loop forever

   while(1)
   {            
       // This method will give you only one character at a time
       // As I can see you are comparing only three characters so 
       // You need to compare when three characters you got from UART

        data[count] = USARTReadChar(); 

        if(data[count] != NULL) // check whether valid data came
          count++;

        if(count > 3)    // this will tell that you got three valid caracters  
        {
            count = 0;  // You can again start comparing  
            if(strcmp(data,old) == 0)  // Here you can use strcmp()
            {
              for(m=0;m<3;m++)
              {
                USARTWriteChar(match[m]);
              }
            }
            else
            {
                for(m=0;m<3;m++)
                {
                    USARTWriteChar(nomatch[m]);
                }
            }       
          }  
       }
    }              
}
```

Comment: Dear Friends, My problem is still unsolved due to my weakness of C language. I need to put my complete code here so that you person can understood well n can help easily, but due to character limit i cant. So tell me if there is other way..

Comment: void main()
{
 
   char *data;
   char *old;
   char *match;
   char *nomatch;
   
   nomatch = "not";
   match = "yes";
   old = "HJB"; 
   int m;
   

   USARTInit(25);    //UBRR = 51

   //Loop forever

   while(1)
   {
  
  data=USARTReadChar();
   
   
   if(strcmp(data,old) == 0)
   {
  for(m=0;m<3;m++)
  {
   USARTWriteChar(match[m]);
  }
   }
   else{USARTWriteChar(nomatch);}
      

   }
}

Comment: This code is not readable in comments. Edit this question to put your code.

Comment: i cant write code here as we generally write in compiler notepad

Comment: Edit your question and write your code there, it will be better. I can see that there is the problem in character reading from UART communication. After reading a character you cant directly do `strcmp`.If I see code properly then can suggest you useful

Comment: The incoming data from USART is "HJB"...so that is same as *old so the condition should be true n again it must be transmit value of *match(i.e "yes") but not as expected.

Comment: As per your suggestion here i had edit my question n also put my main function.